# Python Syntax Highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

I know Notepad++ supports Python but under the language menu I cannot find it! At "P," it only lists 
Pascal, Perl, PHP, Postscript, PowerShell, and strangely, Properties. I am writing some Python scripts and I want the 
syntax to be highlighted. How can I activate Python highlighting?

Comment: Updated to latest version?

Comment: Yeah just updated it. Strangely Python is still not showing.

Comment: In case it still doesn't work for you, http://kib2.free.fr/PyK/ is a free and very good python IDE.

Comment: I had another problem somewhat similar: It shows Python in the P tab but it won't show any Syntax highlighting. --> Try another Design. In my design it had all the same colours, strangely. When I switched the design, everything worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to uninstall and reinstall Notepad++.  Be sure to get the latest version from SourceForge -

http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it's disabled. Check in Preferences | Language Menu/Tab Settings if it's not among the disabled items.

Answer (score 4):

Weird. I have Notepad++ v6.3 on this PC and it is there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure it is not disabled. I happens to me too.

To check go to preferences, click on language items in the left and make sure that python is not in disabled languages.
Reboot notepad++ after applying changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall and install the new version form [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.9.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

On mine, notepad++ v7.5.8, Python is *not* in the P section but it *is* in the bottom of languages menu.

[image: Check out the photo.]

This is the default arrangement for my version of notepad++ so all bets are off if you changed it under settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, python is at the bottom of language list (not under P item - I believe it was moved out of P after I played with Settings) .